# Debian dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant 802.1X wired, internet stops working after dhcp lease timeout

Tags: debian, raspbian, wpa-supplicant

My university started using 802.1X wired authentication recently and my internet connection stops working after dhcp lease timeout on raspberry pi.

I'm using preinstalled dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant to connect to network. After boot the internet works fine, I get IP from dhcp and everything is OK, but after dhcp lease time runs out the internet simply don't work anymore. Only way to get internet working again is to disable and enable interface again (ifdown eth0 and ifup eth0).

I've tried raspbian jessie and also stretch, nothing changed, also I've tried building dhcpcd myself and also I've tried to use dhclient instead of dhcpcd.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

dhclient is not running, but dhcpcd is.

The lease expires mostly after 1 hour.

Also if I connect Pi to my home network, then the connection never drops, so it's probably some problem with re-authentication of something like that.

**dhcpcd.conf**

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
#clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

denyinterfaces wlan0
```

**wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
country=CZ
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
ap_scan=0

network={
    identity="identity@domain"
    password="password"
    eap=PEAP
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    #auth_alg=OPEN
    #proto=WPA RSN
    #pairwise=CCMP
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP IEEE8021X
    ca_cert="path/to/cert.pem"
}
```

**journalctl | grep dhcpcd**

```
Apr 02 23:12:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: waiting for carrier
Apr 02 23:12:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 02 23:12:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: adding address fe80::666d:9cb2:9035:c937
Apr 02 23:12:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: DUID 00:01:00:01:20:4c:53:e2:b8:27:eb:53:ae:55
Apr 02 23:12:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 02 23:12:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: rebinding lease of 158.196.42.184
Apr 02 23:12:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: probing address 158.196.42.184/24
Apr 02 23:12:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 02 23:12:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 02 23:12:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: adding address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 02 23:12:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: adding route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 02 23:12:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: leased 158.196.42.184 for 3600 seconds
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: eth0: adding default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: Too few arguments.
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: Too few arguments.
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: Failed to get unit file state for ntpd.service: No such file or directory
Apr 02 23:12:37 raspberrypi dhcpcd[398]: forked to background, child pid 838
Apr 03 00:15:47 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100 is unreachable, expiring it
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier lost
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address fe80::666d:9cb2:9035:c937
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 00:29:29 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 00:29:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 03 00:29:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 00:29:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 03 00:29:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: rebinding lease of 158.196.42.184
Apr 03 00:29:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 03 00:29:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 00:29:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 00:29:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 00:29:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 00:29:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing address 158.196.42.184/24
Apr 03 00:29:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: leased 158.196.42.184 for 3600 seconds
Apr 03 00:29:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 00:29:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 00:29:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 00:59:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 01:31:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100 is unreachable, expiring it
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier lost
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 03 01:32:42 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 03 01:32:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: rebinding lease of 158.196.42.184
Apr 03 01:32:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing for an IPv4LL address
Apr 03 01:32:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: DHCP lease expired
Apr 03 01:32:48 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.174.198
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Apr 03 01:32:52 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route
Apr 03 01:32:53 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 169.254.0.0/16
Apr 03 01:32:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: offered 158.196.42.184 from 158.196.149.9
Apr 03 01:32:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: ignoring offer of 158.196.42.184 from 158.196.162.8
Apr 03 01:32:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing address 158.196.42.184/24
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: leased 158.196.42.184 for 3600 seconds
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: changing default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 169.254.0.0/16
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 01:32:59 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 01:33:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier lost
Apr 03 01:33:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 01:33:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 01:33:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier lost
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 03 01:33:01 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: rebinding lease of 158.196.42.184
Apr 03 01:33:02 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 03 01:33:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing address 158.196.42.184/24
Apr 03 01:33:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 01:33:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 01:33:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 01:33:06 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 01:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: leased 158.196.42.184 for 3600 seconds
Apr 03 01:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 01:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 01:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 02:03:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 02:40:00 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100 is unreachable, expiring it
Apr 03 03:25:41 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: failed to renew DHCP, rebinding
Apr 03 03:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: DHCP lease expired
Apr 03 03:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 03:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 03:33:11 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr 03 03:33:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: offered 10.5.26.243 from 10.0.0.1
Apr 03 03:33:12 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing address 10.5.26.243/24
Apr 03 03:33:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: leased 10.5.26.243 for 3600 seconds
Apr 03 03:33:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 10.5.26.0/24
Apr 03 03:33:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via 10.5.26.1
Apr 03 03:33:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 10.5.26.0/24
Apr 03 04:03:17 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 10.5.26.0/24
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier lost
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 10.5.26.0/24
Apr 03 11:36:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via 10.5.26.1
Apr 03 11:36:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 03 11:36:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 11:36:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 03 11:36:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 03 11:36:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: rebinding lease of 10.5.26.243
Apr 03 11:36:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: NAK: requested address not available from 158.196.162.8
Apr 03 11:36:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: message: requested address not available
Apr 03 11:36:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr 03 11:36:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: offered 158.196.42.184 from 158.196.149.9
Apr 03 11:36:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing address 158.196.42.184/24
Apr 03 11:36:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 11:36:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 11:36:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 11:36:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 11:36:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: leased 158.196.42.184 for 3600 seconds
Apr 03 11:36:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 11:36:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 11:36:41 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 12:06:40 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 12:38:20 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100 is unreachable, expiring it
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier lost
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 12:58:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: deleting default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 12:58:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: carrier acquired
Apr 03 12:58:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address fe80::ea91:85c:bd9b:85ce
Apr 03 12:58:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: IAID eb:53:ae:55
Apr 03 12:58:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr 03 12:58:27 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: rebinding lease of 158.196.42.184
Apr 03 12:58:30 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: probing address 158.196.42.184/24
Apr 03 12:58:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 12:58:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding address 2001:718:1001:693:aab9:5e4c:7412:6fb7/64
Apr 03 12:58:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 2001:718:1001:693::/64
Apr 03 12:58:31 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via fe80::215:c7ff:fe27:e100
Apr 03 12:58:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: leased 158.196.42.184 for 3600 seconds
Apr 03 12:58:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 12:58:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding default route via 158.196.42.1
Apr 03 12:58:36 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: removing route to 158.196.42.0/24
Apr 03 13:28:35 raspberrypi dhcpcd[838]: eth0: adding route to 158.196.42.0/24
```

Comment: Please update your answer with relevant to dhcpcd logs from your system (i.e. `journalctl`)

Comment: Also please update your answer with details what your configuration looks like. How is dhcp called? Is dhclient still running (`ps`) when the lease expires?

Comment: Thank for replies, I've updated the question with info you requested.

Comment: Not familiar with `dhcpcd`, but it adds and removes a lot of routes; sometimes it seems to remove a route after it has added it (can't make out details from the message alone), and in between it's using a link-local IP 169.254.*.*. If you loose internet, check that you have the correct default route (`ip addr show dev eth0`, `ip route`). And in case `dhcpcd` is acting up, maybe try `dhclient` (Package isc-dhcp-client in Debian, no idea about Raspbian) instead. Is something else running that could set/remove routes?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for reply. I will wait for internet to drop and try to check default route as you're suggesting. Also I can try dhclient (package name is same as in debian) which is installed by default. I don't know about anything that can set/remove routes, but I could be wrong. AFAIK by default on raspbian only dhcpcd is supposed to control network interfaces.

Comment: @dirkt So my internet dropped again few minutes ago, I've checked the `ip addr show dev eth0` and `ip route`, but nothing changed here.

Comment: In other words, even though "internet dropped", you have a valid default route that matches `eth0`? Can you ping the gateway?

Comment: @dirkt Yes, I've had valid default route that matched eth0, wasn't able to test if pinging the gateway worked, because I've restarted the interface. One thing I've tried now is that I've specified lease time in dhcpcd.conf (tried 10 mins) and internet still worked about another 10 mins after lease time runned out. I will wait more time to see if this step fixed the problem. For the mean time thank you so much for trying to help me.

Comment: The lease time is normally set by the DHCP server, so I suppose after 60 mins you'll again run into problems, when the server has to hand out a fresh lease.

Comment: @dirkt You were totally right. The logs said that the IP was leased for 10 mins, but now after 1 hr the internet dropped again. Also I've tried to ping gateway as you asked before, but the ping was unsuccessful with this message `Destination Host Unreachable`.

Comment: @dirkt I've tried to switch to `dhclient`, but after hour the connection dropped again. I've waited until the dhclient tried to renew dhcp lease and then it was stuck at sending `DHCPREQUEST`. I've tried `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` adn then I've noticed that on `ifup eth0` the interface authenticates through `wpa_supplicant` and then gets IP through `dhclient` but when the `dhclient got stuck at `DHCPREQUEST` the `wpa_supplicant` did nothing, no re-authentication. So I think this is the main problem, not the `dhcpcd` or `dhclient`.

Comment: So use `wpa_cli status` to see what `wpa_supplicant` thinks it is doing when the internet connection is lost. Also try `wpa_cli reauthenticate`. BTW, the man page is incomplete, `wpa_cli help` lists all commands. If this is the problem, I'm not sure how to configure `wpa_supplicant` to use a shorter timeout or whatever. You may have to script this somehow.